# Rails 4 unpermitted params that should be permitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm a bit stuck with this one. I'm sure it's simple, but I still can't figure it out.

Here's my permit method:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:char_id, :text).merge!(topic_id:params[:topic_id], user_id: current_user.id, ip: request.remote_ip)
end
```

Here's the controller update method the request is routed to:

```
def update
  @post.update(post_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect to  }
    format.json { render partial: "post", locals: {post:@post} }
  end
end
```

Here's [the params hash](https://gist.github.com/Almaron/d071d86be02796b7eed6) that comes with the request.
I need to get something [like this](https://gist.github.com/Almaron/24d93cb70aeeae18d4eb).

And still when I look in the console I see this:

```
Unpermitted parameters: id, text, char_id, ip, show_text, posted_at, char, editable, deletable, commentable, user
```

Is it something working  wrong or something I missed?

Comment: can you post the full code with the full logs of what params are being submitted? Also, what you *expect* to happen, because that permit method is quite obtuse.

Comment: I've linked a gist with the full params hash I'm getting.

Comment: @sevenseacat I've updated the question with the controller method code. It's quite simple as you can see.

Comment: if it was simple, I wouldnt have asked you for more information. And I still don't know what you're expecting to get out of the permit method.

Comment: Updated with another gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're close, try modifying your `post_params` method to look like this:

```
def post_params
  params.permit(:topic_id)
  params.require(:post).permit(:text, :char => [:id]).merge({ip: request.remote_ip, user: current_user})
end
```

The big difference being we pass `merge` a hash, but also specify what we want from `:char` which is nested inside `:post`, as well as whitelisting `:topic_id` (which is not a part of `:post`).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Except I really don't need that `:char` nesting. I do need the `:char_id`, that comes plainly inside the `post`.

Comment: @Almaron If `:char_id` is inside `:post` you should be able to replace `:char => [:id]` with just `:char_id` and be all set.

Answer (score 0):

I think the merge is the problem. It is in the wrong place.

The way you have it the merge is acting on the params object that results from

```
params.require(:post).permit(:char_id, :text)
```

Try this instead:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).merge(user_id: current_user.id, ip: request.remote_ip)).permit({:char_id, :text, topic_id, :user_id, :ip}
end
```

Comment: tried putting merge before permit, but did not work. also tried to separate them, did not work either.